# 'package:flutter/src/material/search_anchor.dart': Failed assertion: line 940 pos 12: '_anchor != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, searchbar, material3

I am using the `Search bar` and `Search Anchor` in my Flutter project which is newly introduced with `material3`.

I am facing an error while moving back from the `search view`.

It moves back to the `previous screen` if we simply go to the `search` and move back from there.

But if we try to `rebuild` that widget to refresh the UI according to the text in the searchController. It gives me this error.

> Failed assertion: line 940 pos 12: '_anchor != null': is not true.

The error can also be reproduced by moving to the `search view` and performing `hot reload`

This is my search anchor and search bar code

```
 SearchAnchor(
      viewLeading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            controller.closeView("");
            FocusScope.of(context)
                .requestFocus(FocusNode());
          },
          icon:
              const Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
      searchController: controller,
      isFullScreen: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context,
          SearchController controller) {
        return SearchBar(
          key: searchBarKey,
          padding:
              const MaterialStatePropertyAll<
                  EdgeInsets>(
            EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 8.0,
              right: 8.0,
            ),
          ),
          hintText: "Search your notes",
          hintStyle:
              const MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                  TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight:
                          FontWeight.normal,
                      color:
                          Colors.black54)),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {
              _scaffoldKey.currentState!
                  .openDrawer();
            },
          ),
          focusNode: focusNode,
          shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.circular(
                          50))),
          controller: controller,
          onTap: () {
            controller.openView();
            FocusScope.of(context)
                .requestFocus(focusNode);
          },
          trailing: [],
        );
      },
      viewBuilder: (suggestions) {
        return Container(
          height: height,
          width: width,
          color: textFieldBackgoundColor,
          child: const Center(
              child: Icon(
            Icons.mood,
            color: Colors.black,
          )),
        );
      },
      suggestionsBuilder:
          (BuildContext context,
              SearchController controller) {
        return <Widget>[
          const Icon(Icons.abc)
        ];
      }),
```

I am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by converting my `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget`.

So for the people who face this issue in the future

If you are using `StatelessWidget`, try converting it to `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: And, what should we do with the same error in StatefulWidget. May it be, that is wasn't the only change?